# How to pass props in ignite react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass a parameter from a component to another and following is my code.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Otp', {
            mobileNo: this.state.mobileNumber
        })
```

The following is how I am trying to get the value and I am receiving NULL.

```
console.log(this.props.navigation);
```

The output
[image]

When I tried debugger following is what I got.

[image]

I am trying to get the mobileNo variable.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: This issue seems to be of rect-navigation and not ignite.Haven't solved it but started using Redux to store and get data in another component.